# Жуткие тормоза в прокрутке RecyclerView и вылет приложения

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот делаю типа своей галлереи, у меня сделано RecyclerView с секциями заголовками. Когда я загружаю мало фотографий, например 10 секций и по 10 фото, то все отлично. Но когда я загрузил 1000 секций по 32 фотографии(32000 фото), то при прокрутке у меня все виснет намертво, а если дальше пытаться скроллить то и вылет приложения. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно делать, есть сторонняя похожая галлерея, там все плавно скроллится и подгружается, те же фотографии.

```
// АДАПТЕРЫ:         \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

//1:

public static class ItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView iv_images_points; // все изображения в секциях

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iv_images_points = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_images_points);
        }
    }


    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String[]> arrayList;

    public ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String[]> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.z_maket_item_rv_gallery_2, parent, false);

        ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                view.setMinimumHeight(view.getWidth());
            }
        });

        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        String s_path_cam_gall = "";
        String nameImg_s = arrayList.get(position)[0]; //получаем имя

        if (!nameImg_s.equals("")) {

            int minWidth_gall = mapsActivity.minWidth / 3;
            Glide.with(mapsActivity) //
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(Uri.parse("file:///" + mapsActivity.full_Path_catalog_folder_Gallery +  nameImg_s)) //.thumbnail(0.1f)
                    .apply(new RequestOptions()
                            .centerCrop() //
                            .override(minWidth_gall, minWidth_gall)
                            //.skipMemoryCache(true)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE))
                    .into(holder.iv_images_points);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }


}


//2:  (адаптер Секции )

public static class SectionRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionRecyclerViewAdapter.SectionViewHolder> {


    class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView sectionLabel, showAllButton;
        private RecyclerView itemRecyclerView;

        public SectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            sectionLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            showAllButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_show_all_button);
            itemRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_view);
        }
    }

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SectionModel> sectionModelArrayList;

    public SectionRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SectionModel> sectionModelArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.sectionModelArrayList = sectionModelArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public SectionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.z_maket_item_rv_gallery_2_sections, parent, false);
        return new SectionViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SectionViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final SectionModel sectionModel = sectionModelArrayList.get(position);
        holder.sectionLabel.setText(sectionModel.getSectionLabel()[0]);

        //recycler view for items
        holder.itemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.itemRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    /* set layout manager on basis of recyclerview enum type */

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 3);
        holder.itemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);


        ItemRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(context, sectionModel.getItemArrayList());
        holder.itemRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sectionModelArrayList.size();
    }



    //отдельный класс секции
    public static class SectionModel {
        private String[] sectionLabel;
        private ArrayList<String[]> itemArrayList;

        public SectionModel(String[] sectionLabel, ArrayList<String[]> itemArrayList) {
            this.sectionLabel = sectionLabel;
            this.itemArrayList = itemArrayList;
        }

        public String[] getSectionLabel() {
            return sectionLabel;
        }

        public ArrayList<String[]> getItemArrayList() {
            return itemArrayList;
        }
    }

}
```

Нужно как-то сделать, чтобы загрузка фото через Glide не мешала прокруткe(скроллингу), ну и происходила в позиции видимости на экране..

z_maket_item_rv_gallery_2.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="0.5dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#003d829e">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_images_points"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="4sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

z_maket_item_rv_gallery_2_sections.xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:textColor="#c2cad9"
    android:background="#1a2531"
    android:gravity="bottom"

    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_show_all_button"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/d_btn_pnl_4"
    android:text="⋮"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="#b8bcda"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<!--  recycler view for items -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/item_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_show_all_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Загружаю сразу в адаптер:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= points_img_count; i++) {
        .........
        sectionModelArrayList.add(new SectionRecyclerViewAdapter.SectionModel(name_marker, itemArrayList));
    }

    SectionRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new SectionRecyclerViewAdapter(mapsActivity, sectionModelArrayList);
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Основные тормоза с прокруткой идут от того, что в SectionRecyclerViewAdapter в onBindViewHolder постоянно создается при прокрутке ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.. Это можно как-нибудь исправить, чтобы на скроллинг не влияло?

Comment: А с ошибкой какой вылетает? Можете попробовать Picasso

Comment: А подход-то правильный? Может для больших объемов изображений применяется другой подход загрузки изображений в onBindViewHolder? Тут когда много секций и так нет плавности прокрутки, а с большими объемами виснет..

Comment: А ошибка типа - приложение не отвечает, подождать? Похоже на переполнение памяти.. Но если бы все невидимые Image при скроллинге уничтожались, то наверно все нормально бы было..

Comment: А зачем вам рециклер вложенный в рециклер? Для секционирования? Может лучше сделать один RV с титлами (посмотрите, на гите есть библиотеки)?

Comment: Ну чтобы и горизонтальную прокрутку можно было делать(секция в один ряд). Я смотрел вот эту библиотеку, https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter, добавил 500 секций даже без изображений, и на смартфоне она даже не скроллится, виснет намертво..

Comment: Разметку покажите, где вы вставляете свой RV, и разметку элемента.

Comment: А если попробовать в `onViewRecycled` вызвать`Glide.with(mapsActivity).clear(holder.iv_images_points);`?

Comment: А вы грузите все объекты сразу в адаптер или как?

Comment: Да, сразу загружаю, я дополнил код внизу в своем вопросе..